# PDO Prepare and Bind PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on search form. The keywords in the `search` tag will be put in an array Could You show me the way to make the PDO prepare and bind ?

```
$params = array('keywords1', 'keywords2');
```

the query maybe something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `article` 
   WHERE `article`.`title` LIKE '%keywords1%' 
   OR `article`.`title` LIKE '%keywords2%'
```

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 1):

Prepare statement is someting like this.

```
function modify_val( $a ){
    return "%$a%";
}
$params = array('keywords1', 'keywords2');
$newParams = array_map('modify_val', $params);

// the output for the $newParams is like.
//Array
//(
//    [0] => %keywords1%
//    [1] => %keywords2%
//)
```

### Query Improvement: With help of

[@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320436/pdo-prepare-and-bind-php#comment-30325196)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE ";
$query .= implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, count($params), 'article.title LIKE ?'));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $query );
$stmt->prepare( newParams  );
```

First you have to make a connection with your database, Take a look how to make a [PDO database connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the correction, i have modified the answer.

Comment: I really like how you wrapped keywords with `%` :-)

Comment: The next step to functional design could be `implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, count($params), 'article.title LIKE ?'))` :-)

Comment: @zerkms i can't understand this step why i have to use implode, being true i have not used like statement in recent projects yet, but i am little familiar with PDO statements, It would be great if you tell me little more that why do i have to use implode?

Comment: my comment was an improvement proposal - to generate `article.title LIKE ?` `N` times depending on how many `$params` we have passed so that their number wasn't hardcoded